# How can i set heroku dns target to whogohost

Tags: heroku, dns, cname

I have a domain name from whogohost. Iam currently hosting my app on heroku. The url of the website is rhemagist.herokuapp.com. I have tried to set the DNS target from heroku to whogohost. It is however giving me error. So i need some help to fix the error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your client area and  Click on Domains >>> Manage DNS.

Click on Add new Zone Input your domain name without www in the field for Zone Name.

Input this IP address (174.129.25.170) in the IP address field.

Click on the Edit Icon. On the row that begins with WWW, replace your domain name with your Heroku DNS target and save.

Scroll up and click on add record. Copy and paste the shorter CNAME in the Name Field. Select CNAME in the dropdown. Then add your Heroku DNS target in the RDATA field

You can refer to this endpoint: https://www.whogohost.com/host/knowledgebase/121/How-do-I-map-my-domain-to-my-Blogspot-account.html

**NB:** Make sure that on Heroku, when adding your domain name, add it like this: **[www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)** and not just **domain.com**

Comment: With heroku, you don't need a shorter name.
Every other thing works